# What are the differences between \$I_B\$, \$I_b\$, \$i_B\$ and \$i_b\$ in a transistor?

Tags: transistors, symbol

It is quite confusing when I do some calculation with \$I_B\$, \$I_b\$, \$i_B\$ and \$i_b\$. Are they the same? This problem also appears in the current of emitter and the current of collector.

Answer (score 5):

\$I_B\$ means the DC current quantities
\$i_b\$ means the incremental current quantities such as AC signals
\$I_b\$ is used to denote the amplitude of a sinewave
\$i_B\$ is used to represent total instantaneous quantities, for example \$i_B = I_B + i_b\$

Refer the attached image
[image]

Reference: Microelectronic Circuits ~ Sedra/Smith

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/163102/16993) addresses the question quite well, but I feel there is something to add to it because of the general confusion around the "small signal" solution that I've seen around\$^1\$.

When you are given a circuit to solve there probably is a bunch of independent generators in it. Some of them can probably be considered power generators, while other are signal generators. Please note that this partition is **completely arbitrary** unless we agree on some rules on how to classify generators.

That said, we can now solve the circuit using superimposition getting two solutions, one with the power generators on, and signal generators off, the other with all generators powered on. Please note that if you chose carefully how to partition your generators the solution with only signal generators **won't work**\$^2\$. Our solutions will look like vectors of voltages (or currents) and we decide to call them \$V_S\$ (uppercase-uppercase) and \$v_S\$ (lowercase-uppercase), 's' as in solution. The first is the solution with only power gens on, and we love to call it **bias point**, while the second is the whole circuit solution. Now if you subtract the bias point from the whole solution you get what we love to call the **small signal** solution, or some sort of name near that:
$$
v_s = v_S - V_S \text{ (lowercase-lowercase)}
$$
And that's usually quite useful since you normally want to study a circuit's bias point, to be sure you did not screw up, and then study only the signal through it, don't caring about the bias.

The jump between this and the "small signal circuit" is quite big and is usually quite neglected too, at least in my little experience, the fact that the same circuit, with the same topology and all can be used to get the small signal solution is not trivial *at all*.

As others said \$I_b\$ probably refers to some sort of known fixed current but that depends of course.

(1) I am not referring to the linked answer *at all*, it is just a general concern.
(2) That's because superimposition works well with passives but with active components they need to be in the same zone each time you solve the circuit.